# AWS4 request signing with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have a codebase where we work with AWS CloudFront in a limited capacity and am trying to get the status of a distribution invalidation through the API endpoint documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_GetInvalidation.html

This endpoint requires that the request headers are signed using a AWS4 signature, which I'm stuggling with.  I've modeled most of my request signing code based on the signing code in the AWS SDK for Ruby: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb

My code is as follows:

```
class CFAgent

  RFC8601BASIC = "%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ"
  CF_AGENT_ACCESS_KEY = "validaccesskey"
  CF_AGENT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "validsecret"

  def self.cf_dist_invalidation_status
    dist_id = "abc123"
    invalidation_id = "xyz"
    url = "https://cloudfront.amazonaws.com/2017-03-25/#{dist_id}/invalidation/#{invalidation_id}"

    headers = {
      "Content-Type" => "application/json; charset=utf8"
    }
    headers = sign("GET", URI.parse(url), headers, "{}", CF_AGENT_ACCESS_KEY, CF_AGENT_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, "us-east-1")
    puts "signed headers:", headers

    res = SimpleHttp.get(url, headers)
    puts "Status:", res.code
    puts "Body:", res.body
  end

  def self.sign(method, uri, headers, body, access_key, secret_key, region, service_name=nil)
    method = method.upcase
    service = service_name || uri.host.split(".", 2)[0]

    date_header = headers["Date"] || headers["DATE"] || headers["date"]
    date = (date_header ? Time.parse(date_header) : Time.zone.now).utc.strftime(RFC8601BASIC)

    body_digest = hexdigest(body)

    headers['X-Amz-Date'] = date
    headers['Host'] = host(uri)
    headers['X-Amz-Content-Sha256'] ||= body_digest

    headers['Authorization'] = authorization(method, uri, headers, body_digest, date, access_key, secret_key, region, service)
    headers
  end

  private

  def self.host(uri)
    if ((uri.scheme == 'http' && uri.port == 80) || (uri.scheme == 'https' && uri.port = 443))
      uri.host
    else
      "#{uri.host}:#{uri.port}"
    end
  end

  def self.authorization(method, uri, headers, body_digest, date, access_key, secret_key, region, service)
    [
      "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=#{credential(access_key, date, region, service)}",
      "SignedHeaders=#{signed_headers(headers)}",
      "Signature=#{signature(method, uri, headers, body_digest, date, access_key, secret_key, region, service)}"
    ].join(', ')
  end

  def self.credential(access_key, date, region, service)
    "#{access_key}/#{credential_string(date, region, service)}"
  end

  def self.signature(method, uri, headers, body_digest, date, access_key, secret_key, region, service)
    k_date = hmac("AWS4" + secret_key, date[0,8])
    k_region = hmac(k_date, region)
    k_service = hmac(k_region, service)
    k_credentials = hmac(k_service, "aws4_request")
    hexhmac(k_credentials, string_to_sign(method, uri, headers, body_digest, date, access_key, secret_key, region, service))
  end

  def self.string_to_sign(method, uri, headers, body_digest, date, access_key, secret_key, region, service)
    [
      'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
      date,
      credential_string(date, region, service),
      hexdigest(canonical_request(method, uri, headers, body_digest))
    ].join("\n")
  end

  def self.credential_string(date, region, service)
    [
      date[0,8],
      region,
      service,
      "aws4_request"
    ].join("/")
  end

  def self.canonical_request(method, uri, headers, body_digest)
    [
      method,
      Pathname.new(uri.path).cleanpath.to_s,
      uri.query,
      canonical_headers(headers),
      signed_headers(headers),
      body_digest
    ].join("\n")
  end

  def self.canonical_headers(headers)
    c_headers = []
    headers.each_pair do |k,v|
      k = k.downcase
      c_headers << [k,v]
    end
    c_headers = c_headers.sort_by(&:first)
    c_headers.map{|k,v| "#{k}:#{canonical_header_value(v.to_s)}" }.join("\n")
  end

  def self.canonical_header_value(value)
    value.match(/^".*"$/) ? value : value.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip
  end

  def self.signed_headers(headers)
    headers.keys.inject([]) do |signed_headers, header_key|
      header_key = header_key.downcase
      signed_headers << header_key
      signed_headers
    end.sort.join(';')
  end

  def self.hexdigest(value)
    Digest::SHA256.new.update(value).hexdigest
  end

  def self.hmac(key, value)
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, value)
  end

  def self.hexhmac(key, value)
    OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256'), key, value)
  end

end
```

When I call CFAgent.cfinvalidation_status, I receive a 403 error with a "MissingInvalidationToken" code.  "SimpleHTTP" is a simple library that wraps Net/HTTP to make HTTP/HTTPS requests (please assume this works).

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you mean [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), not RFC. That also seems like a lot of code to do this. Are you sure there's nothing in the SDK itself which covers this use case?

Comment: I do mean ISO-8601, thank you (bad choice of variable name but the format should be correct).  The AWS SDK for Ruby does implement this (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb) but I unfortunately can't include that gem for reasons I won't go into.

Comment: If you can't include the gem outright, at least snip out the parts you need. You're trying to re-write this thing here, and doing that without thorough unit tests is going to be trouble. You could test this versus a known-good solution independently, then bundle in your tested, trusted code when it's ready. There's a lot of very subtle things that can go wrong here, so you'll probably have to check that every single header is set *exactly* as expected. I was fighting an issue today with ACL declarations of the form `public_read` being rejected since `public-read` is the actual requirement.

Comment: Why not use the SDK to create an Invalidation request?
 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudFront/Types/CreateInvalidationRequest.html

Comment: Full disclosure, what I have written is more or less a duplicate of Amazon's approach, the main difference being the hexdigest method (Amazon uses an iternal means of deriving that value where I'm attempting to use Digest::SHA256).  I more or less agree with the notion of just using the SDK/ avoid rewriting the header signing code, but am going through the motions of potentially identifying other approaches to some degree.  The team I'm on generally avoids pulling in new gems unless absolutely neccessary.